# Error trying to install symfony command line tools on PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, symfony

I'm running symfony3 and tried to install a symfony command line tools after having installed composer line tools (which get installed without any problems) however, whenever I try to fill the path field for symfony & php, it returns me an error saying :

```
Failed to determine version.
Command /Users/Julien/PhpstormProjects/need4truckSymfony/bin/console /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php -V
Output Symfony installer version 3.0.2
```

I went on JetBrains to find a solution but there is no tips yet for SF3 tools.

I don't have any "console" in the `app/` folder (as it is writen on jetbrains), and I also tried to fill both the fields with `/usr/local/bin/symfony` and `/usr/bin/php` but it doesn't work.

Comment: in symfony3 the console is located at `bin/console`

Comment: Yes it is what I written in my path but doens't work :(

Comment: What is your PhpStorm version?

Comment: 9.0.2. Arf I just see that the Phpstorm 10 releases some bug fixes like "- Symfony 3 support for Command Line Tools" ... Thanks a lot